# Cypher Query for friends of friends filtering out those who are already friends

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have this Cypher query...

```
match (p:Person{userid:8432})-[r:friends_with]->(p1:Person)-[r2:friends_with]->(p2:Person) return p, count(p1), p2 order by count(p1) desc limit 25
```

This returns results (p2) that contain people who are already friends of p. How do I filter out those p2 nodes who are already friends of node p? I tried this snippet from a similar question on this site

```
... where not (p)<-[r:friends_with]->(p2) ...
```

but that does not work. Would appreciate help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that using the following where clause did the trick.

```
where not (p)-->(p2)
```

Comment: It's because of the `r` in your original query. It's already bound for the first rel, so it's not going to match the pattern for the other rel. You should still put the relationship type, if you have more than one type.

Comment: Aah... I see. Thanks for the further insight.